# Change input on selected option function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 `select` and when user select an option the associate value get displayed in an input. I want to use only one function for these 3 select but I have some problem. Here is my **HTML** :

```
<select name="codeLun" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp()">
                    <option value="901549J01" class="Lun">901549J01</option>
                    <option value="901549P13" class="Lun">901549P13</option>
                    <option value="901549P17" class="Lun">901549P17</option>
                    <option value="repos" class="Lun">Repos</option>
                    <option value="autre" class="Lun">Autres</option>
        </select>
<select name="codeMar" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp()">
                    <option value="901549J01" class="Mar">901549J01</option>
                    <option value="901549P13" class="Mar">901549P13</option>
                    <option value="901549P17" class="Mar">901549P17</option>
                    <option value="repos" class="Mar">Repos</option>
                    <option value="autreMar" class="Mar">Autres</option>
        </select>
<select name="codeMer" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp()">
                    <option value="901549J01" class="Mer">901549J01</option>
                    <option value="901549P13" class="Mer">901549P13</option>
                    <option value="901549P17" class="Mer">901549P17</option>
                    <option value="repos" class="Mer">Repos</option>
                    <option value="autreMer" class="Mer">Autres</option>
        </select>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value=""/>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value=""/>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value=""/>
```

And my **JS** :

```
function ModifChamp()
        {
            var conceptName = $('#code').find(":selected").attr('class');
            var codeDay = "heure"+conceptName;
            var i = $('#code').find(":selected").text();
            var x = document.getElementById(codeDay);
            if (i=='901549J01')
            {
                document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                x.text = "6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
                x.value ="6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
            }
    else if(i=='901549P13')
            {
                document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                x.text = "7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
                x.value ="7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
            }
            else if(i=='901549P17')
            {
                document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                x.text = "9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
                x.value ="9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
            }
            else if(i=='Repos')
            {
                document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                x.text = "repos";
                x.value ="repos";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "none";
            }

    }
```

My code work like this, when user select an option from a `select` it will affect the corresponding input thanks to the ID. But the problem is that it's always the first select which is selected. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykvr61rL/) but it didn't work at all on jsfiddle

Why the first select is always selected ?

Comment: 1st look .. Id must be unique .. change id="code" to class="code"  and in js use . instead of #   $('.code')

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Yep, I changed Id to class but the problem don't come from this I think

Comment: @SimonM.  yes after class you have to pass this see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code http://jsfiddle.net/ykvr61rL/3/

> **Removed id and use class**

**Now why I am passing this in function because now we have same class name
so this will give you current selected scope only**

```js
function ModifChamp(scope) {
  var conceptName = $(scope).find(":selected").attr('class');
  console.log(conceptName)
  var codeDay = "heure" + conceptName;
  console.log(codeDay)
  var i = $(scope).find(":selected").text();
  var x = document.getElementById(codeDay);
  if (i == '901549J01') {
    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display = "block";
    x.text = "6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
    x.value = "6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
  } else if (i == '901549P13') {
    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display = "block";
    x.text = "7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
    x.value = "7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
  } else if (i == '901549P17') {
    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display = "block";
    x.text = "9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
    x.value = "9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
  } else if (i == 'Repos') {
    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display = "block";
    x.text = "repos";
    x.value = "repos";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="codeLun" class="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Lun">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Lun">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Lun">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Lun">Repos</option>
  <option value="autre" class="Lun">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMar" class="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mar">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mar">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mar">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mar">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMar" class="Mar">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMer" class="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mer">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mer">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mer">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mer">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMer" class="Mer">Autres</option>
</select>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value="" />
```

**EDIT USING JQUERY**

---

```js
$('.code').change(function() {
    var conceptName = $(this).find(":selected").attr('class');
    var codeDay = "heure" + conceptName;
    var i = $(this).find(":selected").text();
    var x = $('#' + codeDay);
    console.log(x)
    if (i == '901549J01') {
        x.show()
        x.val("6h 11h30  14h 20h00");
    } else if (i == '901549P13') {
        x.show()
        x.val("7H15 11H31 14h02 19h");
    } else if (i == '901549P17') {
        x.show();
        x.val("9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54");
    } else if (i == 'Repos') {
        x.show();
        x.val("repos");
    } else {
        x.hide()

    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="codeLun" class="code" >
  <option value="901549J01" class="Lun">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Lun">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Lun">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Lun">Repos</option>
  <option value="autre" class="Lun">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMar" class="code" >
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mar">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mar">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mar">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mar">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMar" class="Mar">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMer" class="code" >
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mer">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mer">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mer">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mer">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMer" class="Mer">Autres</option>
</select>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value="" />
```

Comment: Not exactly. There are still inconsistencies. For example input fields do not have `.text` and only necessary to get the codeDay once and it can be gotten with jQuery too

Comment: @SimonM. i updated answer and added solution using jquery also

Comment: Now one more change and it looks like my version apart from my switch

Comment: lol jquery function are same so you tell me what can i change

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version

- class instead of ID
- use of data-attr
- removal of DOM access
- caching of objects
- use of switch - an object like `{ "901549J01": "6h 11h30  14h 20h00"... }` would be even more elegant

```js
$(function () {
    $(".code").on("change", function () {
        var $sel = $("option:selected", this);
        var val = $sel.val();
        var conceptName = $sel.data('day');
        var $dayField = $("#heure" + conceptName);

        switch (val) {
            case '901549J01':
                $dayField.val("6h 11h30  14h 20h00").show();
                break;
            case '901549P13':
                $dayField.val("7H15 11H31 14h02 19h").show();
                break;
            case '901549P17':
                $dayField.val("9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54").show();
                break;
            case 'repos':
                $dayField.val("repos").show();
                break;
            default:
                $("#heureAutre").show();
        }

    });
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="codeLun" class="code">
    <option value="901549J01" data-day="Lun">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13" data-day="Lun">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17" data-day="Lun">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos"     data-day="Lun">Repos</option>
    <option value="autre"     data-day="Lun">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMar" class="code">
    <option value="901549J01" data-day="Mar">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13" data-day="Mar">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17" data-day="Mar">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos"     data-day="Mar">Repos</option>
    <option value="autreMar"  data-day="Mar">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMer" class="code">
    <option value="901549J01" data-day="Mer">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13" data-day="Mer">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17" data-day="Mer">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos"     data-day="Mer">Repos</option>
    <option value="autreMer"  data-day="Mer">Autres</option>
</select>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value="" />

<input class="hide" type="text" name="heureAutre" id="heureAutre" value="" />
```

---

Much more generic version with less html

```js
$(function () {
    var times = ["6h 11h30  14h 20h00", "7H15 11H31 14h02 19h", "9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54", "repos"],hours = {}, vals=[];
    $("#Lun>option").each(function () { // assuming each sel will have the same
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (val != "autre")  vals.push(val);
    });
    $.each(times, function (i, time) {
        hours[vals[i]] = time;
    });
    $(".code").on("change", function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var $dayField = $("#heure" + this.id);
        $("#heureAutre").toggle(val == "autre"); // if we have one per day, this code needs fixing
        if (val != "autre") {
            $dayField.val(hours[val]);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="codeLun" class="code" id="Lun">
    <option value="901549J01">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos">Repos</option>
    <option value="autre">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMar" class="code" id="Mar">
    <option value="901549J01">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos">Repos</option>
    <option value="autre">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMer" class="code" id="Mer">
    <option value="901549J01">901549J01</option>
    <option value="901549P13">901549P13</option>
    <option value="901549P17">901549P17</option>
    <option value="repos">Repos</option>
    <option value="autre">Autres</option>
</select>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value="" />
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value="" />

<input class="hide" type="text" name="heureAutre" id="heureAutre" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested change `id` to `class` and attach an `change` event to all `.code` and you can remove inline `onchange` from `html` as below:

```js
//change Event for all the select
$('.code').on('change',function(){
  //get respective elements and data using $(this) which refers to current select
  var conceptName = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('class');
  var codeDay = "heure"+conceptName;
  var i = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  var x = $("#"+codeDay);
  if (i=='901549J01')
  {
    $(x).show().text("6h 11h30  14h 20h00").val("6h 11h30  14h 20h00");
    //keep it in a single line
  }
  else if(i=='901549P13')
  {
    $(x).show().text("7H15 11H31 14h02 19h").val("7H15 11H31 14h02 19h")
  }
  else if(i=='901549P17')
  {
    $(x).show().text("9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54").val("9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54")
  }
  else if(i=='Repos')
  {
    $(x).show().text("repos").val("repos")
  }
  else{
    $(x).hide()
  }
});
```

```css
.text{
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="codeLun" class="code">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Lun">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Lun">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Lun">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Lun">Repos</option>
  <option value="autre" class="Lun">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMar" class="code">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mar">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mar">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mar">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mar">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMar" class="Mar">Autres</option>
</select>
<select name="codeMer" class="code">
  <option value="901549J01" class="Mer">901549J01</option>
  <option value="901549P13" class="Mer">901549P13</option>
  <option value="901549P17" class="Mer">901549P17</option>
  <option value="repos" class="Mer">Repos</option>
  <option value="autreMer" class="Mer">Autres</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureLun" id="heureLun" value=""/><br/>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMar" id="heureMar" value=""/><br/>
<input class="text" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="heureMer" id="heureMer" value=""/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use it like this

html

```
<select name="codeLun" class="code" >
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.code').on('change',function(){
            {
                var conceptName = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('class');
                var codeDay = "heure"+conceptName;
                var i = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                var x = document.getElementById(codeDay);
                if (i=='901549J01')
                {
                    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                    x.text = "6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
                    x.value ="6h 11h30  14h 20h00";
                }
        else if(i=='901549P13')
                {
                    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                    x.text = "7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
                    x.value ="7H15 11H31 14h02 19h";
                }
                else if(i=='901549P17')
                {
                    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                    x.text = "9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
                    x.value ="9H06 11H24 14H06 15H54";
                }
                else if(i=='Repos')
                {
                    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "block";
                    x.text = "repos";
                    x.value ="repos";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById(codeDay).style.display= "none";
                }

        }

     });
 });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/x03cyewj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, because you are using the same id on every select, using it as a selector always retuns the first one.

A quick change in your code would be:

1.- Use `this` on every call to your function

```
<select name="codeLun" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
...
<select name="codeLun" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
...
<select name="codeLun" id="code" onChange="ModifChamp(this)">
...
```

2.- Change your function to read the element and decide based on it

```
function ModifChamp(element){
    var conceptName = $(element).find("option:selected").attr("class");
...
```

See it working: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ykvr61rL/5/)**